# unable to install python-dev and libapache2-mod-wsgi on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, mod-wsgi

When I run the command `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi python` it says

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package libapache2-mod-wsgi is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package python-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  python2-dev python2 python-dev-is-python3

E: Package 'libapache2-mod-wsgi' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'python-dev' has no installation candidate
```

I tried running python2-dev, python2, and python-dev-is-python3 and all of them just a had a variation of the error above. The goal of the whole thing is to hist a Flask website. -Rick

Comment: I happened to be seeing this a few days ago. but no config changes in my repos or system that I can find that explain further. I'm wondering what has been changed in the repos.

Comment: >> my prev comment - should have read "what has been changed in the repos or my script ..."  I've been using that for several years. but suddenly this message and I'd like some pointers on how to begin debugging/resolving.